# Is it possible to transfer files from Amazon S3 directly to another web server?

Tags: file-transfer, webserver, amazon-s3

I need to transfer some files from several Amazon S3 buckets to a different web server.

The amount of data is several gigs, so downloading and re-uploading is not favorable.

I have done some research and found that there is a command line utility [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) that may be capable of doing this, but it seems that this needs to be run from the web server, and I'm not sure if I have the ability to install it.

My web server options for backup are shared hosting with Bizland and a VPS with Host Gator.

Has anyone done something like this before?  Would a php script be capable of accomplishing this if the software isn't an option?

My apologies for the newb-ish question, it's my first one here on superuser.. be gentle! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access to the web server, you may be able to log in (using a tool such as [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) if you're on Windows) and remotely copy the files over HTTP, using a tool like wget or curl.

A PHP script could also accomplish this (it's just downloading over HTTP and saving to the local file system) but a command-line tool will likely be quicker and easier.